# Compute ACF for a grid of time series in Python

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I am trying to compute the ACF for a grid of time series using python. `statsmodels.acf` only accepts 1D time series, so using `xr.apply_ufunc` for instance is not a viable solution. (Note that I am using `xarray` as my preferred package here, since I deal with large multi-dimensional labeled datasets)

I figured it would be easiest to write the ACF from scratch and vectorize that. Trimming the `statsmodels.acf` down to just the skeleton I need to get going:

```
from numpy import correlate as npc
from scipy.signal import correlate as spc

def acf(x, nlags=40):
    """
    ds : xarray DataArray with gridded time series
         e.g., dims ('time', 'lat', 'lon')
    nlags : number of lags to compute ACF out to 
    """
    avf = acovf(x)
    acf = avf[:nlags + 1] / avf[0]
    return acf

def acovf(x):
    xo = x - x.mean('time')
    n = x['time'].size
    lag_len = n - 1
    d = n * np.ones(2 * n - 1)
    acov = npc(xo, xo, 'full')[n - 1:] / d[n - 1:]
    return acov
```

This is currently breaking at the `npc` line. `np.correlate` as well as `scipy.signal.correlate` break with anything larger than a 1D time series or give an undesired answer.

Most directly: **How can I vectorize a discrete linear cross-correlation of many time series on a grid?**

Using the example:

```
x = xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(10,2,3), dims=['time', 'lat', 'lon'])
```

If I run `npc(x, x, 'full')` I get the error:

```
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

If I run `spc(x, x)` I get a (19, 3, 5) array that does not contain accurate output. My output should be (N*2-1, lat, lon) where N is the number of time samples.

This issue seems to be the bottleneck in vectorizing the ACF -- if I can get the cross-correlation to work, the rest of the `acf` and `acovf` functions should be simple to vectorize.

Comment: The computation of correlation work "time series by time series", what part do you aim at vectorizing? And for what practical purpose (code readability or performance)?

Comment: I essentially want to avoid looping through each time series to perform this -- I usually work with lat/lon data so that's O(N^2) with a double for-loop. If I can vectorize the cross-correlation, then this should achieve the overall goal. I'm looking for performance over readability.